# OCaml Summation

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to make a function in OCaml which does the summation function in math.
I tried this:

```
sum n m f =
    if n = 0 then 0
    else if n > m then f
    else f + sum (n + 1) m f;;
```

However, I get an error - "Characters 41-44: else f * sum(n + 1) m f;; Error: Unbound value sum
and sum is underlined (has carrot signs pointing to it)

I looked at this: [Simple OCaml exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775075/simple-ocaml-exercise)
It's the same question, but I see a lot of other things that I do not have.
For example, for my n = m case, I do not have f n and then in the else case, I do not have f m.

Why do you need f n if you want the function to return an integer? D:
What's the problem!? Thanks in advance.

Comment: on an unrelated note, your function is not tail-recursive. It will use up stack space equal to the range of the numbers. You might want to make it tail-recursive, by having an internal helper function that passes along an accumulator

Comment: (succ n) is more natural than (n + 1) in Ocaml

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot `rec`.

`let rec sum n m f = ...`

For recursive functions, you must manually include the "rec" keyword.

Answer (score 4):

1. You must use the keyword `let` to introduce a new function, and `let rec` when this function is recursive.
2. Why is the first argument named `f`? If it is a function you should apply it to something.
3. `if n = 0 then 0` what a strange convention! Are you sure you want this? Idem for `if n > m then f`

For now, your code is equivalent to

```
let sum a b c =
  if a = 0 then 0
  else if a > b then c
  else if a < 0 then min (-a*c) ((b-a+1)*c)
  else (b-a+1)*c
```

Comment: Nice info! I also did realize that my function was only really multiplying a number after I tested it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
# let rec sum c = function
    (0,_)          -> 0
  | (n,m) when n>m -> c
  | (n,m)          -> c + sum c (n+1,m)
        ;;

# sum 2 (3,5);;
- : int = 8
```